# Power green LED from microbial fuel cell (MFC)

Tags: led, discharge, supercapacitor

I am looking for a way to power green LED (like GNL-3012GD) from MFC which provides 0.2mA @ 0.6V for about 1hr (there should be some drop off period then; 2..3hrs to restore). I understand that the amount of power is too small but what about the energy storage to drive the LED for a while (from a few seconds)?
Any hints or schematics are highly welcomed.

Comment: If you need about 2.4 V and 1 mA to power the LED, 0.2mA @ 0.6V for about 1hr will give you about 10 minutes at 50 % efficiency. But to convert only 0.6 V will be very hard. What about a MFC stack of 4 or more cells in series to get 2.4 V or more?

Comment: @Uwe Unfortunately, I need to use only one cell, this is a restriction.

Comment: For how long do you need to "power green LED"? What are the criteria of LED being "powered"? Is the naked eye visibility sufficient?

Comment: @Ali Chen The naked eye visibility could be sufficient. However, it would be nice to store the energy and power led on then for a few seconds.

Comment: What is for about an hour?  You need to power the LED for an hour?  The MFC provides .2mA @0.6V for an hour?  For the MFC, I assume there is some drop off period where power supplied does not match the spec.  Can you edit the question to clarify this?

Comment: @Jaden Yes, you right, there should be some drop off period (2..3hrs to restore). However the MFC can provide .2mA at 0.6V during one hour. I need to use (accumulate) the power for using led then.

Comment: Spend some time looking at boosting ICs.  Keep track of the few that come closest to your needs.  If you have choice of LEDs, keep track at the few that come closest to your needs, i.e. low power and trading voltage and current may add choice to your design.  If you do find something that can boost that source, start looking for storage devices.  Document what you find.  Document the limitations of the options you find.  Assuming this is a school project, document how close the current technology can get you to your goal and report that.

Comment: Can you manually switch the current?

Comment: I didn't know that mcd stands for Millicandela. Here is a [link](https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/light/mcd-to-lumen-calculator.html) to a conversion calculator for finding lumens.

Comment: @Jaden mcd is a unit of measure for luminous intensity which is a better indicator of visibility than lumens which is total luminous flux. LED lumens is different than incandescent light bulb lumens. Lumens are measured isotropically where LEDs are anisotropic devices. Incandescent light bulbs are isotropic light sources.

Comment: Added an update to my answer that appears to be an excellent solution for your project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, here are some considerations.

1. Your source has the energy storage of 0.6V* 0.2 mA * 1hr = 120 uW-h.
2. If you get some newer LEDs, say [LTST-C193TGKT-5A](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/lite-on-inc/LTST-C193TGKT-5A/160-1832-1-ND/2356255) chip LED from Lite-ON, it has a fairly high efficiency, about 100 mcd at 5 mA., not the miserable 7 mcd @ 20 mA as for GNL-3012GD, or 50 times more efficient. I just run a test, so the light is pretty visible at 16 uA (micro Amp !!!), with forward voltage about 2.3V. This equates to power consumption at just 37 uW, while you can see the light with no mistake. If I take a proportion of 100 mcd and 16/5000, this is about 0.32 mcd of light, and there are many LEDs with 0.1 - 0.3 mcd light output. So the 0.32 mcd is pretty visible.
3. Now, if you find some "energy-harvesting" IC operating at 500-600 mV, with output boost to 2.3-2.5 V, something like the module from [Advanced Linear Devices](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Advanced%20Linear%20Devices%20INC%20PDF/EH4295prelim.pdf), or LTC3108, the LTST-C193TG LED will be glowing (at 0.32 mcd) for up to 3 hours.

The hints here are (1) high-efficient LED, and (2) energy-harvesting IC.
Would it fit your requirements?

Comment: @ Ali Chen Wow! Brilliant to run the test with so efficient led! Thank you very much. The problemi is that I am asked to use GNL-3012GD only! (this is a requirement)

Comment: The GNL-3012GD will likely emit the distinctive level of light at 1 mA (1/20 of 7 mcd = 0.35 mcd). At 2V it is 2 mW. If you manage to harvest the energy from your cell using a booster to 3 V into a 4700 uF capacitor, your LED will work for about 10 seconds.

Comment: What about the very new 18,000 mcd Brightek QBL7IG30C?

Comment: @Misunderstood, the OP clearly stated that the junk GNL-3012GD is the requirement.

Comment: How much time will it take to harvest 2 mW from the 0.12 mW source?

Comment: @Misunderstood, 2 mW for 10 seconds is 0.02 J. You can harvest 0.02J from 0.00012 W source in 167 hours. This is a lot, and a leakage can be a problem, and booster efficiency, but theoretically...That's what the student challenges are for.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about "the junk GNL-3012GD is the requirement"  The GNL-3012GD is a green 3mm radial lead LED just like the QBL7IG30C which could push 300 mcd with 300 µA (18,000 mcd @ 20 mA).  Your replacement is an SMT with a dismal 154 mcd @ 5 mA.  If I were to choose an SMT replacement it would be an OSRAM Oslon SSL which has the highest efficacy of any green LED available today.

Comment: @Misunderstood, you must be reading wrong specifications. The GNL-3012GD is an old standard LED with 7 mcd at 20 mA, https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/773/DOC002773602.pdf

Comment: And your  LTST-C193TGKT-5A  is only 154 mcd @ 5 mA which is the one I was saying was inadequate.  I'm recommending 4,500 mcd @ 5 mA.  Very new LED, just released.

Comment: Okay, 167 hrs, that's more than I guessed. So a nearly invisible 10 second, 0.32 mcd flash every 7 days?  What would be the point to that?  The OP wanted 2-3 hr restore time and 1 hr run time.

Comment: @BenVoigt, thanks, I messed up. 166,6 seconds is right. The units of power (mW) have a connotation of continuous transfer, so one can't have 2mW output from 0.12mW source, as the comment was implying. That's why I tried to convert all thing into joules, but messed up hours and seconds. Thanks again.

Comment: CORRECTION: 2 mW for 10 seconds is 0.02 J. You can harvest 0.02J from 0.00012 W source in 167 seconds, not hours.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 7/17/2018**
Ran across a Texas Instruments Ultra Low-Power Boost Converter With Battery Management for Energy Harvester Applications.  It appears to be an excellent and well documented solution for your project.

[bq25504 IC datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25504.pdf)

[Eval board for bq25504](https://store.ti.com/BQ25504EVM-674-BQ25504-Battery-Management-Evaluation-Board-Ultra-Low-Power-Boost-Converter-IC-Energy-Harvester-P2689.aspx)

End of Update

---

1 hour run time and 2-3 hr restore time is currently not possible.

Theoretically, with 100% efficiencies, it would take at least 16 hours to harvest enough energy to light an LED for 1 hour.

A harvesting module at this input power would be 25-50% efficient best case.

It appears the MFC cannot sustain the stated 0.6V @ 200 µA and needs few hours to charge its energy capacity to deliver 1.2 mW.

It may be possible if you have a couple of days to harvest the required energy.

You need more voltage. Voltage must be more than the LED's forward voltage.
You need more power, like at least 2 mW, you have 0.12 mW.  Even if you were to boost the voltage there would not be enough power.
Harvesting the power would take more than 2-3 hours. You need 16x more power than you have.
Your LED is too inefficient. A 18,000 mcd [QT-BrightekQBL7IG30C](http://www.qt-brightek.com/datasheet/QBL7XX30C.pdf) would do better but still not enough voltage or power.

Comment: I see no reference to the total mWh provided by the power source. If boosting is possible, storage of energy in a device may be possible.  i.e. can you show that a very efficient power harvesting approach will not collect enough power to light a very efficient LED for 1 hour?  That is the work needed to declare 'not possible.'

Comment: @Jaden how many hours would it take to harvest a 0.12 mW source to get 2 mAh?

Comment: Why are you saying "A run time of few seconds with a 1 week restore time" when you calculated the duty cycle of ~1/16 ?

Comment: @Misunderstood I commented at the declaration 'It cannot be done'.  I refer you to the accepted answer.  I also encourage you to accept that there are probably things you do not know and to try to do things that others say cannot be done.  Or, at least, try not to discourage others from looking at the possibilities.

Comment: @BenVoigt that was based on the answer to my question posed to Ali Chen.  It sounded high but he usually gets things correct.  The ALD EH4295 like it may or may not do the job with a questionable best case efficiency of 25-50%.  Also based on where the OP something about the MFC not being able to sustain the output for more than an hour:---  "should be some drop off period (2..3hrs to restore). However the MFC can provide .2mA at 0.6V during one hour."---  Not enough is known about the MFC.  It appears the MFC needs 2-3 hrs to charge then can provide the 200 µA for an hour. New est. 2-3 days

Comment: @Jaden and I edited my answer immediately after you made the first comment on the possibility and the required 2-3 hr charge time to sustain 1 hr.  Currently it is not possible as it may take as much as 2-3 days to harvest enough energy to light the LED for an hour.  Unless you have a better estimate.

Answer (score 1):

It may be done using no electronic DC/DC converter at all. Just use an electromechanic voltage multiplier.

You need 4 or 5 super capacitors connected in parallel by a multipole switch. Charge the capacitors for one hour. Then operate the switch by hand connecting the capacitors in series and to the LED. May be a resistor in series to the LED for current limiting.

The switch should have a pair of dual throw switches for each capacitor.

There will be no electronic losses, just the very small leakage currents of the capacitors and the switches. Electronic analog switches should not be used, their leakage current is too high.

There will be an RC time constant when charging and also when discharing the supercaps. During charge, the internal resistance of the MFC will be part of the R(C), not only the wiring resistance. The internal resistance of such a low power source may be quite high. About 3 RC time constants will be needed for a 95 % charge. If the capacity of the supercaps is too big, charging will take a very long time, but there is more energy stored to operate the LED longer.

Of course the effective capacity of 4 supercaps in parallel is 4 times the capacity of a single one. The effective capacity of 4 supercaps in series is 1/4 of a single one.

Comment: Thank you, Uwe! This is very clear and easy to try. I guess that the supercap should be at 3.3... 3.7V (0.6V x 5 caps). What about capacitance? The caps will be charging via the wires of MFC ( a few Ohms), so it looks like we have RC constant.

Comment: @MikhailGaichenkov, Per my calculations and assumptions about your LED (2V 1mA visible), you need total 5-8mF to run the LED for 10 seconds (CV^2/2). You will need 4 caps (0.6*4=2.4V and ~300 Ohm resistor for LED), so four 22mF supercaps should do the job. Plus-minus.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean... that is neither enough voltage or current to directly drive ANY led.  You could possibly use a boost IC like [This](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Analog-Devices-Linear-Technology/LTC3105EDDPBF?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvi6wO7nhr1L5jAaXeL3JiLcdO4a6sYtl4%3D) To boost the voltage up to power the led then slowly charge a capacitor from that and switch on the led once it is charged.  I don't believe that the switching process could be automated as I believe that even a 555 timer would use up more power than that MFC could supply.

Comment: But will the LTC3105 operate with only 0.2mA @ 0.6V at input? I found no information about operation with only 0.2 mA in the datasheet.

Comment: Thank you. Agree, we can charge a capacitor from LTC DC/DC converter for hours. but how to switch the led on then and so on?

Comment: What about a manually operated switch to connect the LED to the charged capacitor? If no manual operation, a fully mechanic clock switch for delay.

Comment: But you need a fairly large capacitor with very low leakage current, smaller than the already small load current from the DC/DC converter.

Comment: Any suggestions, the type of the capacitor? If the charhge current is about 0.1..0.2mA, the leakage << 0.1mA

Comment: The charge current after conversion will be much lower than 0.2 mA. [Super capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitors) have the high capacity and low leakage current.

Comment: The LTC3105 has a diagram showing no-load input current at 0.2 mA at input voltage of 0.6V, figure 3105-G16, page 5. So it looks like the entire cell power will be wasted before producing any useful output. Probably the LTC3105 isn't up to this task, it needs something better.